# If $\int _0^1|f_n(t)-f(t)|dt \rightarrow 0 $ then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _0^1f_n(t)dt =\int _0^1f(t)dt$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $\int _0^1|f_n(t)-f(t)|dt \rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ then how to prove that

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _0^1f_n(t)dt =\int _0^1f(t)dt$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$
0 \le \left| \int_0^1 f_n(t)\,dt - \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt \right| \le
\int_0^1 |f_n(t)-f(t)|\,dt
$$